# how can we record the screen with audio in ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: screen, audio-recording, desktop-recording

in my computer i've got ubuntu 22.04 LTS I've tried many screen recording apps none of them work. only screen cast work but there no audio in it(nothing but only the video).

Comment: Try this, hope it works for you >> https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/record-desktop-with-sound-ubuntu-2204/

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[Kazam](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/kazam) works for me in Xorg session. You can install it via the terminal:

```
sudo apt install kazam
```

Comment: doesn't work with Wayland

Answer (score 0):

This one works decent for ubuntu 22.04 [gnome sound recorder](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/SoundRecorder)

sudo apt-get install gnome-sound-recorder -y

make sure the input microphone is on as well

Comment: Is needed video + sound (not just sound).